# Google Cloud AutoML Vision API - Service account custom-vision@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-automl, automl, vision-api

I am currently working on a tutorial about the [Google Cloud AutoML Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/tutorial).

When I try to execute this command (step 8):

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding [our-project-id]
--member="serviceAccount:custom-vision@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
--role="roles/storage.admin"
```

I receive the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.add-iam-policy-binding)
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Service account custom-vision@appspot.gserviceaccount.com does not exist.
```

It is a Google provided global service account.
How do I fix it?

Comment: hm and are AutoML Vision APIs enabled for the same project you're using in gcloud command?

Comment: yes, cloud vision api is enabled

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating the tutorial you followed in my project as well and encountered the same error.

As a workaround, I searched for other tutorials and found this one [1](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/before-you-begin). I followed the steps and did not encounter the issue anymore.

Comment: But this tutorial is not about the global "custom-vision@appspot.gserviceaccount.com" service account. Still have the same error at step 8. Did you change anything else?

Comment: Based on the error, as this is a global service account, it is not being used anymore.